# Change group in joomla registration

Tags: joomla, registration, acl

I need to change default group when new user registers in Joomla! 2.5. Right now default group is `Registered` - number 2 in #__user_usergroup_map Group_id column.

I tried to change variable here, (e.g `$system = '33';`) but it didn't worked:

```
    $this->data->groups = array();
    $system = $params->get('new_usertype', 2);
    $this->data->groups[] = $system;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to modify the core files for this.

There is a simple config for this very purpose:

1. Go to the `User Manager`

   [image: User config menu]
2. Click on the <kbd>Options</kbd> button.

   [image: Setting button]
3. Select the default group.

   [image: Default group option]

I tested this with the latest version of J!2.5.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need to make a ability for users to choose from groups.

Comment: But this is not the question that you asked. I think that it will be a sham to add a long edit to this answer, that is not very short anyway. I don't think that I should delete it, since it may provide assistance to someone who considered needlessly hacking the core files to do this. I suggest you accept this answer (as it does answer the original question) and start a new one describing what you want to do. I can probably point you in the right direction there.

Comment: @user1876234, Here is [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552738/268093) to a question very similar to the one you intended to ask.