# Allow users to select user group from custom Joomla login form

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, custom-component, usergroups

I am developing a website in Joomla 3.0. What I am trying to do is to create a custom login form. The reason I want to do that is to enable users to select the user group they want to be put in while they are registering. So I need to create a dropdown box in the login form. From this dropdown box users would be able to pick up the desired user group. So far I've tried using various plugins and extentions but the problem is that they can't be customized the way I want. So please, if you have any idea how to achieve the result I am looking for share it with me. I guess I will have to try to code it myself, but even in this case I would need a lot of help. Giving me tips and citing good tutorials would also be helpful.
Thank you

PS: If you have solution to my problem for another version of Joomla please share it with me.

Comment: How well do you know Joomla and PHP? Usually customizing a component that does most of what you want is a lot easier than writing one from scratch.

Comment: I personally would not use the ACL groups for this purpose but you could have such a field as part of a profile plugin.  You could then on the appropriate events add to the user group maps.  There is of course a core field with the user groups but  you wouldn't want people to be able to select Super Admin

Comment: MasterAM = Well, honestly I am new to Joomla and PHP but I don't find them quite difficult. What components do you think I can customize?

Comment: Elin = What components would you use? Have you found such a profile plugin? And how would you use the user group maps? It would be really helpful for me. 10x

Comment: You can make a profile plugin similar to the one in the core and make a checkbox or other field. You could also copy and modify the standard groups field that is used in the user manager.

Comment: Check out my answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259784/8197303

Answer (score 2):

Probably [UsergroupSelector](http://function90.com/products/usergroup-selector.html) plugin can help you to achieve this. This plugin adds a field in registration form. In case if you do not want to use default html, then you need to add a select box html in your overrided template.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for adding a custom field during the user registration process is probably using a plugin.

You can use a commercial plugin that is available called [Multi-Profiles Registration](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/frontend-access-control/20450) (demo [here](http://www.joomapp.com/component/users/?view=registration)), that appears to be doing exactly what you want (I have never tested it).

This will cost you some money and save you some time, but I will layout the alternative way, which is developing your own plugin.

Lucky for you, there is an excellent tutorial [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1858258), which is actually a chapter form a book called [Joomla! Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013278081X) (especially page 5 of the tutorial).

Writing a plugin takes time and I will not go over all of the details.
The main steps include:

- Create a plugin configuration file, that will include a list of groups to select from (form element). This is where you (or anyone using the plugin) will select the groups available for registration (groups can be fetched via `UsersHelper::getGroups()`).
- Augment the registration form with a select box that includes the desired user groups from the plugin config. This can be done by creating a layout override for your template (`templates/<your template>/html/com_users/registration/approval.php`) or by injecting it into the document at some phase of the render event by the plugin, which is probably the preferred method if this plugin should be portable.
- Set the desired group by the plugin by processing the form data and overriding the `groups` data parameter on the `onUserBeforeSave` event.

Comment: Oh god, thank you for this good answer, I haven'y even expected a better one. Could you tell me how much knowledge of PHP do I have to possess to write this plugin? :)

Comment: You need to know PHP and the Joomla framework. PHP is not that hard to master if you know another OO programming language. Joomla has some basic tutorials and API reference. The tutorial that I linked to should provide you with most of what you need once you feel sufficiently comfortable with PHP and basic Joomla.

Comment: There is an aricle about making a profile plugin in the docs.joomla.org site or you can actually just add xml to the profile folder of current one

Comment: @Elin, I believe that you are referring to [this article](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin), that seems pretty good. Both my suggestion and this tutorial target the same user creation event and take similar approaches, but I like the field injection method taken in the tutorial that you proposed better.